# Programmatically make a click or touch an item in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to force a click or touch an item on a recyclerview?

I found people talking to use a command `recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0).itemView.performClick()` but `recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0)` always returns null!

I want initially that the first recyclerview item is clicked/ touched.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView.performClick();

            }
        },100);
```

Comment: It's worked for me Thanks @Kshitij Arora